# Multiprocessing, does join prevent processes from working in parallel?

Tags: python-2.7, multiprocessing

I'm quite new to multiprocessing, and have been trying to find an answer to this question but not succeeding.

Given two processes, if I use `.join`, does the second process begin in parallel with the first process, or does it wait until the first process is completed?

If the latter, how do I let the processes work in tandem?

```
import multiprocessing

def worker():
    x = 0
    for i in range(2000000):
        x+=1
    print x

def worker2():
    x = 0
    for i in range(10000000):
        x+=1
    print x


if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker2,)
    q.start()
    q.join()

    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker,)
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`join()` make the main process wait the subprocess to terminate; prevent second process from starting.

Place `join()` after the start of the second process to run both process parallely.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker2,)
    q.start()

    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker,)
    p.start()

    q.join()
    p.join()
```

Comment: Ahh, okay. So what's the advantage of even using join in this circumstance?

Comment: @kylex, to make sure the process terminated. If you want to run  process (B) that should be run after process (A) complete their job, you should use `A.join()`.

Comment: @kylex, See [Programming guidelines from multiprocessing documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#all-platforms), (esp. Joining zombie processes)

Comment: that makes sense, I guess I'm confused as to how one would go about making safe parallel processes then. Created a new question for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18139901/multiprocessing-how-to-run-processes-in-parallel-without-creating-zombies