# Multiprocessing, how to run processes in parallel without creating zombies?

Tags: python-2.7, multiprocessing

I'd like to run the processes in parallel, so I commented out a `p.join` from the `__main__` section.
What are the consequences of not have a `.join`, or better yet, should I be using a different approach for parallel multiprocessing?

```
import multiprocessing

def worker(num):
    x = 0
    for i in range(10000):
        x+=1
    print x, num

if __name__ == '__main__':

    for i in range(4):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(i,))
        p.start()
        # p.join()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join the processes after starting them.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    procs = []
    for i in range(4):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(i,))
        p.start()
        procs.append(p)
    for p in procs:
        p.join()
```

---

If you run multiple similar tasks, you can use [multiprocessing.Pool](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool).

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    pool.map(worker, range(4))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Comment: Pool seems to split the actual work up correct, as opposed to running the task independently within each process?

Comment: @kylex, `pool.map(worker, range(4))` is like call `worker(0)`, `worker(1)`, `worker(2)`, `worker(3)` parallely. But run only within specified process count (default: cpu count).